# What does this mean? dative and prepositional cases and ни

Tags: грамматика

Такой юной девочке ни к чему подобный «маскарадный» вариант макияжа.

How do I translate it? It doesn't make sense to me.

To such a young girl...

Comment: “Ни к чему” means “is unsuitable” (in more literal uses one could say “ни к чему не подходит” — “matches nothing”). Does this make it clear?

Comment: and there's a derivative adjective ***никчемный*** - *useless; good for nothing*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ни к чему" is an idiom, it literally means "completely useless", "inapplicable", etc. It is often used as "inappropriate", which is your case exactly: "Such thick makeup is completely inappropriate for such a young girl."

UPD. The commenters raised a good point: "completely useless" here means "completely useless [for you]/[in this situation]". It doesn't mean the object in question is fundamentally useless. Maybe simple "does not need" is a better translation, e. g. "Such a young girl does not need such thick makeup."

Comment: ...or: "isn't needed" (which isn't quite the same as "useless").

Comment: or ***is of no use***